# Guarantee of copying before moving

Tags: c++, move

For given sample code:

```
struct some_struct_t {
    std::string key;
    // other fields;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, TSomeStruct> hashmap;

some_struct_t some_struct;
// filling some_struct

hashmap[some_struct.key] = std::move(some_struct);
```

Is there a guarantee that `some_struct.key` will be got as a key for `hashmap` *before* moving `some_struct` into `hashmap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a guarantee that `some_struct.key` will be got as a key for hashmap
>   before moving some_struct?

Yes.

`std::move()` doesn't actually move. It is more like a cast from an lvalue-reference to an rvalue-reference. The actual move (if any<sup>1</sup>) happens during assignment proper, which is sequenced after evaluating the left-hand side of the assignment operator.

<sup>1</sup> The move will happen if the the assignment resolves to a move assignment or a copy assignment that receives its argument by value and utilizes the move-constructor.

Answer (score 2):

expression can be rewrited as:

```
hashmap.operator[](some_struct.key).operator=(std::move(some_struct));
```

so first call will be `operator[]` and than `operator=`

Comment: This answer does not take into account the two important nuances of this code, which is that the evaluation of those function calls is _sequenced_, and that it is not the `std::move` that does the moving (otherwise you _would_ potentially have a problem). As such, it's not really an answer to the question.